# Swift Embedded Framework That Depends on Swift Package

Tags: ios-app-extension, ios-frameworks, swift-package-manager

My iOS app follows the "Photos Extension" template:
 - A standalone, "container" app
 - A Photo Editing extension, which is deployed by embedding it within the app above.

As suggested by Apple, code that is **shared** by both the app and the extension is gathered in a "core" **cocoa framework** that is embedded in the app, and to which both the app and the extension are linked.

So my Xcode project contains **three targets**:

- The **Framework** target,
- The **Photo Editing Extension** target, which links to the Framework but does not embed it, and
- The **App** target, that embeds the Extension binary and the Framework binary, and links to both.

**So far, so good.**

---

Furthermore, the framework, the app, and the extension depend on two libraries **MyLibraryA** and **MyLibraryB** I have on Github (and in turn, **MyLibraryA** depends on **MyLibraryB**).

I originally set the dependency on **MyLibraryA** and **MyLibraryB** using Carthage, **and everything was working fine**.

---

*Then*, I decided to migrate my libraries A and B to Swift Packages.

I removed all Carthage-related settings in project and targets, framework search paths, etc. to make sure the Swift Package versions of my libraries are referenced and not the cached Carthage builds. I also deleted the Carthage directories (checkouts *and* build).

#### The Problem

When I build the shared/embedded **Framework** target, there are no issues.

But when I try to build either the **App** or **App Extension** targets, I get an error pointing to the shared frameworks Swift header (MyFramewor-Swift.h):

```
// ...
@import CoreGraphics;
@import CoreImage;
@import Foundation;
@import PhotosUI;
@import UIKit;
@import MyLibraryA;  <-- Module 'MyLibraryA' Not Found
// ...
```

And the resulting:

> Could not build Objective-C module 'MyFramework'

I know frameworks that are *distributed as binaries* cannot depend on Swift packages, but this embedded framework is *compiled locally* from source code *and then embedded*.

**Perhaps there are some changes I can make to my setup on Xcode to get it to work?**

I tried changing `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` to `No` in the **Build Settings** for the Framework target, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can currently set `Install Objective-C Compatibility Header` to `No` in Build Settings for modules that require a Swift Package dependency.

This's probably due to "Swift Packages" being "Swift", but still looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try it as soon as I get to my desk.